# Follow an user in twitter via Rest API

Tags: api, rest, twitter

How using the twitter rest api can i follow a user in something like this format:

> http://myuser:mypassword@urloftwitterapi/follow?user=useriwannafollow

There is a very simple method like this? **Thanks**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joost already posted take a look at:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

If you want to use this longer than till the end of June you'll need to check out OAuth Authentication:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/ 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Because Twitter will drop basic HTTP Auth by June 30th:
http://www.countdowntooauth.com/

That means you'll need some library by then, if you don't want to go with with something like Python or Ruby, you could check out Twurl: http://github.com/marcel/twurl/

Answer (score 1):

Use friendships/create:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-friendships%C2%A0create